# Why do padding and margins take precedence over height/overflow of something?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to create a table such that there are 2 rows. The top row contains 2 columns, the bottom row contains one column. I want the top and bottom rows to have a fixed height and the overflow to be hidden. I don't care if the text is too big, just that the heights remain constant.

Why is it that when I add text in header tags (h1, h2, etc.) that the row expands to allow for the text to fit? I want the extra stuff to just be hidden.

What am I doing wrong? Here is some code:

```
<style>
.top-right-cell,
.my-top-row {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.my-bottom-row {
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr class="my-top-row">
        <td class="top-left-cell">Something</td>
        <td class="top-right-cell"><h1>Something else.</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my-bottom-row">
        <td class="bottom-cell" colspan="2">Something longer that takes 2 columns.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PpT2C/

The layout isn't the important part. I just want to know why padding and margins seem to take precedence over the height and overflow properties.

Comment: table will expand/shrink to the content it holds, table-layout can fix width only and overflow is not usable, unless tr are formated as block elements, but then, it doesn't 'layout' like table does normally

Comment: @GCyrillus - So do you think divs would be a better way to go about it?

Comment: Yeah, use divs for better consistency.

Comment: That is, as long as you don't use `display:table-cell` and stuff, because then you'd be facing the same problem!